# How Google redirector link or 2.bp.blogspot link generated from http://*.googlevideos.com/*?

Tags: google-drive-api, http-redirect

1. This link : https://r9---sn-cvh7zn7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=10bc30daeba89d81&itag=22&source=picasa&requiressl=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-cvh7zn7s&ms=nxu&mv=m&pl=19&gir=yes&clen=28147982&dur=186&lmt=1439597374686662&mime=video/mp4&mt=1439599172&ip=115.187.58.15&ipbits=0&expire=1439628005&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,gir,clen,dur,lmt,mime&signature=5F12A9860DCBD622A1E7CBFFECAB28789FD4C1D2.461477172E2BDF3F55AA0A13A63CBA7C06FFAA1A&key=ck2

redirects from this link: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/bO0q678cHRVZqTDclb33qGUXve_X1CRTgHMVz9NUgA=m22

I want to know how to get this redirect link to go to my google drive videos.